# How can I compare two different sized data sets using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am working on creating a script that compares two Excel sheets for differences and then writes the results of the comparison to a new CSV file. I have tried following tutorials but I get an error when trying to run my script: "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects". What am I doing wrong?

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd


pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 2500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 2500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 2000)

df1 = pd.read_excel('Old Budget.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel('New Budget.xlsx')


diffs = df1[df1!=df2]

df1[df1!=df2].to_csv ('Differences.csv', index = False, header=True)

print (diffs)
```

My example data frames:

```python
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14],['kelly', 10], ['mark', 15], ['james', 14]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
df
```

```python
import pandas as pd
data = [['tom', 60], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 10],['kelly', 10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age'])
df
```

Thanks.

Comment: `df1.dropna` is simply a function object. To call it you'd do `df1.dropna(inplace=True)` if you want to change the existing dataframe. Sometimes its best to just reasssign the dataframe: `df1 = df1.dropna()`.

Comment: We don't have your excel files and since they aren't really that important to the answer, consider just initializing two dataframes with differences you want to test. Then we can copy and run your code.

Comment: @tdelaney Ok, just added two data frames to my post. Hopefully everything is formatted correctly, I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) operation:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['tom', 10], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 14], ['kelly', 10], ['mark', 15], ['james', 14]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])
data = [['tom', 60], ['nick', 15], ['juli', 10], ['kelly', 10]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Age'])

df1 = df1.rename(columns={'Age': 'Old Age'})
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'Age': 'New Age'})
df3 = df1.merge(df2)
df3 = df3[df3['Old Age'] != df3['New Age']]

print(df3)
# Output:
#    Name  Old Age  New Age
# 0   tom       10       60
# 2  juli       14       10
```

Comment: Thanks. I am getting a key error when I try to translate this answer into my business requirements. ```import pandas as pd

cols= [0,1,2]
df1 = pd.read_excel('Servers.xlsx', usecols=cols)
df2 = pd.read_excel('ServersIntl.xlsx', usecols=cols)

df1 = df1.rename(columns={'IP': 'Old IP'})
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'IP': 'New IP'})
df3 = df1.merge(df2)
df3 = df3[df3['Old IP'] != df3['New IP']]

print(df3)```